# Combining multiple rows of data to one row per id

Tags: sql, group-by, netezza

I have a raw data that has multiple dates per category, and I use code `case when category = 'referral' then min(date) end as date_referral` to get earliest dates of each category per id.

However, it will not return data in a row but create row per category, as such:

```
id    date_entered      date_referral      date_reply        date_final
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      2020-12-20           null              null              null 
1      2020-12-20         2020-12-21          null              null 
1      2020-12-20           null            2020-12-21          null 
1      2020-12-20           null              null            2020-12-24
```

I tried enforcing single rows by using `distinct` or `group by` (separately and together):

```
select distinct id
, date_entered
, case when category = 'referral' then min(date) end as date_referral
, case when category = 'reply' then min(date) end as date_reply 
, case when category = 'final' then min(date) end as date_final

from data
group by id
, date_entered
, category
```

but it will keep returning multiple rows, with each row being calculated earliest date per category. I also tried creating cte after this code to `select distinct id, date_entered, date_referral, date_reply, date_final from table` but that also still returns multiple rows..

How can I combine these rows and make it return one single row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not group by `category`.
Use conditional aggregation like this:

```
select id, date_entered,
       min(case when category = 'referral' then date end) as date_referral,
       min(case when category = 'reply' then date end) as date_reply, 
       min(case when category = 'final' then date end) as date_final
from data
group by id, date_entered
```